# How can I get Google Cloud to stop billing me?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm new to google cloud.  I set up some billing alerts and quickly realized that I would spend too much money.  I deleted all that I thought I had created under the compute and container engine tabs.  I also disabled my billing account.  But, I continue to be billed!  Any ideas on what I should do?

Comment: Stackoverflow got nothing to do with billing issue. I suggest to contact their customer support, instead of seeking for assistance here.

Comment: You can request help from Google Cloud billing here: https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing

Answer (score 3):

To close a billing account you must be a billing administrator on the account. Billing accounts cannot be deleted.

Note: Before you close an active billing account, you must move its associated projects to another billing account or disable billing for its projects.

To close an account:

1. Go to the Cloud Platform Console.
2. Open the console left side menu and select Billing  Billing
3. If you have more than one billing account, select the billing account name.
4. Click Close billing account.

> Note: After you close your billing account, we will bill you for the usage you accrued prior to cancelling your service. This bill will be the last bill you receive, unless you reactivate service.

[Create, modify, or close your billing account](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6288653?hl=en)